# Entries and specific comments mysql codeigniter

Tags: mysql, forms, codeigniter

I'm having struggle since 2 days. I can't get the entry_id for each entry  which get passed to the view by $post on my comment form.

Is there a better solution to connect entries and the specific comments?..
I'm pretty new and don't really have a clue of the opportunities I have.

Entry table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entry` (
`entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`entry_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`entry_body` text NOT NULL,
`entry_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

comment table:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `comment_body` text NOT NULL,
  `comment_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Model:

```
class System_model extends CI_Model
{

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

function get_all_posts()
{
    //get all entry
    $query = $this->db->get('entry');
    return $query->result();
}

function add_new_entry($name,$body)
{
    $data = array(
        'entry_name' => $name,
        'entry_body' => $body,
        'entry_id' => $id
    );
    $this->db->insert('entry',$data);
}

function add_new_comment($post_id,$commentor,$email,$comment)
{
$data = array(
    'entry_id'=>$post_id,
    'comment_name'=>$commentor,
    'comment_email'=>$email,
    'comment_body'=>$comment,
);
$this->db->insert('comment',$data);
}

function get_post($id)
{
$this->db->where('entry_id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get('entry');
if($query->num_rows()!==0)
{
    return $query->result();
}
else
    return FALSE;
}

function get_post_comment($post_id)
{
$this->db->where('entry_id',$post_id);
$query = $this->db->get('comment');
return $query->result();
}

function total_comments($id)
{
$this->db->like('entry_id', $id);
$this->db->from('comment');
return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
}
```

Controller:

```
   function index()
   {
    //this function will retrieve all entry in the database
    $data['query'] = $this->system_model->get_all_posts();

    $this->load->view('main',$data);
}

function add_new_entry()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));

    //set validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('entry_name', 'Title', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[200]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('entry_body', 'Body', 'required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        //if not valid
        $this->load->view('add_entry');
    }
    else
    {
        //if valid
        $name = $this->input->post('entry_name');
        $body = $this->input->post('entry_body');
        $this->system_model->add_new_entry($name,$body);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '1 new entry added!');
        redirect('/system/index/');
    }
}


public function post($id)
{
$this->load->database();
$data['query'] = $this->blog_model->get_post($id);
$data['comments'] = $this->blog_model->get_post_comment($id);
$data['post_id'] = $this->db->insert_id();
$data['total_comments'] = $this->blog_model->total_comments($id);

$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));

//set validation rules
$this->form_validation->set_rules('commentor', 'Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comment', 'required');

if($this->blog_model->get_post($id))
{
    foreach($this->blog_model->get_post($id) as $row)
    {
        //set page title
        $data['title'] = $row->entry_name;
    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //if not valid
        $this->load->view('system/post',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        //if valid
        $name = $this->input->post('commentor');
        $email = strtolower($this->input->post('email'));
        $comment = $this->input->post('comment');
        $post_id = $this->input->post('post_id');

        $this->blog_model->add_new_comment($post_id,$name,$email,$comment);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '1 new comment added!');
        redirect('system/post/'.$id);
    }
}
else
    show_404();
}
```

View:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
        <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Blog</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h2>This is my blog</h2>
    <?php if($query):foreach($query as $post):?>

    <h4><?php echo $post->entry_name ;?> (<?php echo $post->entry_date ;?>)</h4>
    <?php echo $post->entry_body ;?>

    <?php echo form_open('system/post');?>
    <p>Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="commentor" />
    </p>
     <p>Email:<br />
    <textarea name="email" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>Kommentar:<br />
     <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="50" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
     </p>

     <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post->$entry_id; ?>" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     <?php echo form_close();?>

     <?php endforeach; else:?>
    <h4>No entry yet!</h4>

    <?php endif;?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is kinda unclear as to what you are asking. This works, but you want to know if there is a better way? If that is your question, it seems a little subjective. There are always ways to improve code. Improve design, structure etc.

Comment: the thing is it doesn't work.. im having a problem to get the entry specific id on my view.. im getting this error: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: entry_id

Filename: views/main.php

Line Number: 26

Comment: Okay that helps. Remove the $ in front of it. $post->entry_id; not $entry_id; does that work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the $ from the column name field. Should be $post->entry_id;

Remove the argument from the post function in your controller

```
function post(){
   $entry_id = $this->input->post('entry_id');

   .... the rest of your code. 
}
```

you could also create a function outside of this post function to do the same

```
function get_data_from_post(){
   $for each variable you have =  $this->input->post('variable_name');
}
```

then you could call that too. may not be needed though.

Comment: at least im not getting the error while loading my view.. this one is fixed but as soon as i submit the filled forms i get this error:

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for System::post()

Filename: controllers/System.php

Line Number: 62

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: controllers/System.php

Line Number: 65

Comment: see my edits. You get that message because your not passing the value directly in the end of the url like ?entry_id=post_id

Comment: CodeIgniter has a wonderful documentation set. you should check it out.

Comment: my biggest problems are with the URIs and .htaccess im too dumb to understand the logic..

Comment: i usually just use the post array. sometimes you can use the uri helper within codeigniter too. Like I said, check the documentation, great info and tutorial type explanations of the libraries and functions.

Comment: Wow I have done everything now.. it's amazing. The URLs seperate page view now everything works.. thanks for the great motivation and help man.